# Sprint Boot Controller method called twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I don't know what's wrong with my code, my rest service getting called twice.

Annotations in my controller class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.java")
@Controller
```

Here is my sample code:

Rest Service:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUserDetails(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "userId") String userId){
        log.info("UserId:"+userId);
        return "content_home";
    }
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>myappname</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <location>\\path\folder\test</location>
            <max-file-size>10240</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>51200</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>51200</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myappname</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/waffle-filter.xml,
            /WEB-INF/myappname-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

I deployed this war file in tomcat8.5 server.

I tried below and all cases service is getting called twice

1. Tried to hit the rest service from IE, Chrome, Mozilla, Postman
2. I commented @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.java") as my myappname-servlet.xml is doing a component scan but no luck.
3. I tried with @ResponseBody in front of the return type of method - Actually this way it's getting called only once but I need to return a jsp not the body. So it won't work out.
4. I verified network tab in developer tools, request is placed twice as
   below
   1st. Type = Document, Initiator = other
   2nd. Type= text/html, Initiator = resturl

Any suggestion or help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `@RestController` not `@Controller` as for starters (unless u got @RequestBody as well`. point 4 states that **You** are invoking endpoint twice.

Comment: @Antoniossss - As I mentioned in point 3, when I used (@ResponseBody) it's calling only once but it returns the String not the jsp. Here I need to return content_home.jsp.

Comment: So its not REST controller ;P

Comment: Ok. Let's call it Spring controller.What are my options?

Comment: Post all both request-response coontents so I can see actual requests.

Comment: But first request ends with 200, so its your frontend fault. You are making 2 calls, nothing related to controller to me. Requests bascily are started by client, thus you need to search for culrpit on client/frontend side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158183/discussion-between-s-k-and-antoniossss).

Comment: Did you load spring boot also?
I had similar problem after adding spring boot to already working project and not configured properly.